# How to "address" a flight plan to additional stations

Tags: air-traffic-control, general-aviation, terminology, flight-planning

Airspace around the Swiss village of Davos is restricted as part of the [World Economic Forum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Economic_Forum) every year. [The amendment](https://www.austrocontrol.at/jart/prj3/ac/data/dokumente/LO_SUP_2022_04_en_2022-04-26_0704195.pdf) to the [Austrian AIP](https://eaip.austrocontrol.at/) instructs pilots who would still like to cross the affected airspace as follows:

> (...) flight plans have to be addressed additionally to:
> **LOWWYWYW**

How do I "address my flight plan" to a station other than the ATC at dept./arr. airports? The code given is also too long for an ICAO airport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code `LOWWYWYW` is an [AFTN Address](https://skybrary.aero/articles/aeronautical-fixed-telecommunication-network-aftn) (Aeronautical Fixed Telecommunication Network), identifying an AFTN station. In this case a sub-structure of the ATC organisation of an international airport.

`LOWW` designates [Vienna Int. Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vienna_International_Airport), while `YWY` designates a [Military Flight Operational Control Centre](https://iata.codes/airline/military-flight-operational-control-centre-ywy). <s>The final `W` is likely a filler.</s> The final `W` designates yet another subdivision of `YWY`.

Flight plans can be addressed to these AFTN stations using the field of the same name in the official ICAO flight plan. Some flight plan filing systems may require you to toggle *'switch to ICAO form'* (or similar) to display this field:

[image]

will show the relevant field at the very end of the form:

[image]

Comment: The `X` in `LOWWYNYX` in the SUP header is an example of a filler that you mention, but the last `W` for the answer would be a subdivision of `YWY` per Doc 4444 11.2.1.2.3.2. Nice Q&A!